# Mikrotik RouterOS - How to prevent all devices in a VLAN from initiating any connections outside of the VLAN?

Tags: vlan, mikrotik, routeros

I'm using a RouterOS device as a router on a stick.

I'd like to isolate a certain VLAN from the outside world so that the VLAN cannot instantiate any connections to other VLANs or to the Internet (WAN).

I've set up the following firewall rule:

```
/ip firewall filter
add chain=forward \
    action=reject reject-with=icmp-admin-prohibited \
    connection-state=!established,related,untracked \
    in-interface=vlan120
```

It works for `ping`:

```
ping www.google.com
PING www.google.com (172.217.20.4) 56(84) bytes of data.
From _gateway (192.168.120.1) icmp_seq=1 Packet filtered
```

It works for `tcp`:

```
telnet www.google.com 80
Trying 172.217.20.4...
Trying 2a00:1450:400d:805::2004...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Cannot assign requested address
```

But it does not work for `udp`:

```
nc -z -v -u time1.google.com 123
Connection to time1.google.com 123 port [udp/ntp] succeeded!
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: It's a false success message. See [Why do netcat scans for UDP ports always succeed?](https://serverfault.com/questions/797763/why-do-netcat-scans-for-udp-ports-always-succeed)

Comment: UDP is not connection-oriented, so it has no feature like "established."  Every packet is independent.

Comment: Ok I learned from the link from Michael's comment that: a UPD packet is considered to be successfully delivered unless there is an ICMP reject. There is no way to know that a packet has been delivered unless there is a response sent back from the remote host. My question is: can I set up the Mikrotik router to send an ICMP reject for UDP packets?